# Expand data frame and add a new variable

Tags: r

I have a data frame structured like this:

`+----------+------+--------+-------+
| Location | year | group1 | Value |

+----------+------+--------+-------+
| a        | 2020 |      1 | x     |
| a        | 2020 |      2 | y     |
| a        | 2020 |      3 | z     |
| a        | 2021 |      1 | x     |
| a        | 2021 |      2 | y     |
| a        | 2021 |      3 | z     |
| b        | 2020 |      1 | x     |
| b        | 2020 |      2 | y     |
| b        | 2020 |      3 | z     |
+----------+------+--------+-------+`

I would like to expand the data frame to include 3 rows for every location, year, and group1 combination and generate a group2 variable that identifies these new combinations (1-3). Ideally, the data frame will look like this:

`+----------+------+--------+-------+--------+
| Location | year | group1 | Value | group2 |
+----------+------+--------+-------+--------+
| a        | 2020 |      1 | x     |      1 |
| a        | 2020 |      1 | x     |      2 |
| a        | 2020 |      1 | x     |      3 |
| a        | 2020 |      2 | y     |      1 |
| a        | 2020 |      2 | y     |      2 |
| a        | 2020 |      2 | y     |      3 |
| ...      |  ... |...     |...    |...     |
+----------+------+--------+-------+--------+`

I was able to expand the dataframe to the correct number of total rows using the following code:

`df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)),3), 1:4]`

But couldn't figure out how to add the group2 variable shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyr` you can use `expand` - this will expand your data frame to all combinations of values with your sequence of 1 to 3:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Location, year, group1, Value) %>%
  expand(group2 = 1:3)
```

**Output**

```
   Location  year group1 Value group2
   <fct>    <dbl>  <int> <fct>  <int>
 1 a         2020      1 x          1
 2 a         2020      1 x          2
 3 a         2020      1 x          3
 4 a         2020      2 y          1
 5 a         2020      2 y          2
 6 a         2020      2 y          3
 ...
```

Your approach looks close, and I suppose you could just add on `group2` like this:

```
cbind(df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each = 3), ], group2 = 1:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you are looking for

```
library(dplyr)

# 1. Data set
df <- data.table(
  location = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b"),
  year = c(2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021,2020,2020,2020),
  group1 = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
  value = c("x","y","z","x","y","z","x","y","z"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# 2. Your code to expand data frame
df <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 3), 1:4]

# 3. Arrange
df <- df %>% arrange(location, year, group1, value)

# 4. Add 'group2'
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(location, year, group1, value) %>% 
  mutate(group2 = cumsum(group1) / group1) %>% 
  arrange(location, year, group1, value, group2)
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

We can use `crossing` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
crossing(df1, group2 = 1:3)
# A tibble: 27 x 5
#   Location  year group1 Value group2
#   <chr>    <int>  <int> <chr>  <int>
# 1 a         2020      1 x          1
# 2 a         2020      1 x          2
# 3 a         2020      1 x          3
# 4 a         2020      2 y          1
# 5 a         2020      2 y          2
# 6 a         2020      2 y          3
# 7 a         2020      3 z          1
# 8 a         2020      3 z          2
# 9 a         2020      3 z          3
#10 a         2021      1 x          1
# … with 17 more rows
```

Or create a `list` column and then `unnest`

```
df1  %>%
       mutate(group2 = list(1:3)) %>% 
       unnest(c(group2))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Location = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "b"), year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L), group1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), Value = c("x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```